# ERROR: sllgen:make-rep-loop: unbound identifier in module in: sllgen:make-rep-loop

Tags: scheme, racket

```
    (define read-eval-print (sllgen:make-rep-loop "--> "
(lambda (pgm) (eval-program pgm))
(sllgen:make-stream-parser
 the-lexical-spec
 the-grammar)))
```

Is anyone familiar with this type of error?
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right language.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/eopl/), it looks like you need to start your source file with `#lang eopl`:

```
#lang eopl

(define read-eval-print
  (sllgen:make-rep-loop
   "--> "
   (lambda (pgm)
     (eval-program pgm))
   (sllgen:make-stream-parser
    the-lexical-spec
    the-grammar)))
```

Once you do this, of course, you'll start getting some other errors, e.g., that `eval-program` isn't defined.  If you define a dummy one, e.g.,

```
(define (eval-program pgm)
  (values))
```

You'll then get an error that

> `sllgen:make-stream-parser`: bad scanner specification in: `the-lexical-spec`

You'll need to replace that lexical specification with an actual specification, and similarly (I expect, though I didn't explore this far) with `the-grammar`.  The documentation linked above might (or might not) help you out with those.  It looks like you can get the code for the book that this is based on, *Essentials of Programming Languages*, from [the book's website](http://www.eopl3.com/code.html).

What really looks the most promising, though, are results like

- [Environment-Passing Interpreters,  Programming Language Essentials, 2nd edition, Appendix: The SLLGEN Parsing System (PDF)](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/plt-2005-1/a_sllgen.pdf)
- [SLLGEN tutorial (PDF)](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/383/havens/notes/Lecture11.pdf)
- [sllgen source (sllgen.scm)](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/csg711/f05/eopl/code/interps/sllgen.scm) ([a somewhat older version](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/course/purdue/cs565/S97/code/sllgen.scm))
- other sources (I found the above just by [searching with Google for sslgen](https://www.google.com/search?q=sllgen))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I am using eopl as #lang and I still get the same error.

Comment: @user2227735 What version of Dr. Racket are you using?

Comment: Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.6, english by PLT.

Comment: @user2227735 Hm, I've got "Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3, english by PLT."  The code I posted above, in a file by itself, runs and gets to the _new_ error that I described (and that should be expected at this point).  Maybe you need to make sure that Dr. Racket is selecting the language based on the `#lang` directive. Maybe you need to install the eopl langpack somehow?

Comment: I will try this out. In the mean time, could you tell me how to call a separated-list? I want to call this: (expression
      (primitive "(" (separated-list expression ",") ")")
      primapp-exp)
   
   (primitive ("car") car-prim)

Comment: I am using (eval "car (2,3,4)");

Comment: @user2227735 I don't know what that's supposed to do.  Typically, if you wanted to call `car` with the list `(2 3 4)`, you'd just write `(car (list 2 3 4))` or `(car '(2 3 4))`.  In either case, it sounds like it's a _different_ question that this one, so you should ask it as a new question, not as a comment in this question.